Can't connect to Amazon RDS MySQL instance (Error 2003 HY000 - Can't connect to MySQL server)
I'm trying to connect to my Amazon RDS MySQL instance from my local machine using MySQL Workbench and the MySQL CLI, but I keep getting the following error:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'sdfs.cfo6mykwwjpf.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306' (10060)


Things I've tried:

RDS Instance is Publicly Accessible:

In the AWS RDS console, the Publicly accessible option is set to Yes.


Security Group Configuration:

I have configured the security group to allow inbound traffic:

Type: MySQL/Aurora
Port: 3306
Source: My IP address (verified by selecting the My IP option in the security group rules).




MySQL Workbench:

I'm using MySQL Workbench to connect

Hostname: sdfs.cfo6mykwwjpf.eu-north-1.rds.amazonaws.com
Port: 3306
Username: root
Password: Correct (I’ve double-checked this multiple times).





Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm not sure what else I could be missing in the configuration or setup. Thanks in advance!

If I am not mistaken you cannot access RDS instance directly over the internet. Please find this re:Post that will guide you on how to access your RDS instance from local machine via a Bastion host : https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/rds-connect-ec2-bastion-host

When diagnosing RDS instance connectivity issues there's a few layers to peel back.

Is the instance using the correct subnets (public for public access, private for almost all other situations)
Is the DB configured to be publically accessible if you're using public subnets
Does your security group allow the connection you're trying
Do you have the correct credentials

The first two are pretty easy to check in the AWS console, but the easiest possible way to test external connectivity is to test with telnet:
telnet my-db-hostname 3306
If you make a successful connection then you've established the following:

DB is in the correct subnet
DB is configured to be publically accessible
DB has correct security group and security group rules

So if all that works, then the only possibility is you've got the wrong credentials. In your situation I think you're using the wrong username root, which should be admin if you're using aurora
p.s: You  might want to modify your question and remove the hostname
